# Convergence of recursive sequence $a_{n+1} =\frac{ 1}{k} \left(a_{n} + \frac{k}{a_{n}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$ a_{n+1} =  \frac{1}{k} \left(a_{n} + \frac{k}{a_n}\right) ; k>1, a_1>0 $$ The problem is to show that it converges.

**Attempt:** The sequence is not monotone but it has a lower bound. It seems that odd terms subsequence and even term subsequence are monotonic sequences (I wrote some basic code to make this observation) though I am not able to prove it analytically. I also know that if odd subsequence and even subsequence converge to same limit then the sequence also converges. So, that tells me that I am on the right track.

Please provide any hints.

Comment: is this $$a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_k+\frac{k}{a_k}\right)$$?

Comment: No. See the pic from the book. It's problem 7
https://imgur.com/zujzuYA

Comment: $k$ is supposed to be an integer ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM no. But I don't think it matters. If 0<k<1 then the sequence is monotone. So that's why it assumes k to be greater than 1

Comment: @Rahul: Can you tell us which book (author, title, edition)?

Comment: @quasi Mathematical Analysis by S C Malik & Savita Arora, 5th edition, New Age International Publishers.
Here's a link to the Amazon page.
https://www.amazon.in/Mathematical-Analysis-S-C-Malik/dp/9385923862/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Comment: Are you familiar with fixed points, particularly attracting fixed point? Is it ok to use "heavy artillery"? Just an example of what I mean https://www.math.ubc.ca/~andrewr/620341/pdfs/fp_sum.pdf, for example one immediate result is that $x^{*}=\sqrt{\frac{k}{k-1}}$ is the unique fixed point for $f(x)=\frac{1}{k}\left(x+\frac{k}{x}\right)$ and it's also attracting since $|f'(x^{*})|=\left|\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{(x^{*})^{2}}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{k}-\frac{k-1}{k}\right|=\left|\frac{2-k}{k}\right|<1$

Comment: @rtybase From your discussion, all you know so far is that $x^*$ is attracting in the (infinitesimal) vicinity of $x^*$. You need to show attraction, however, for any starting point $x_1 > 0$. There is more work to do. One possible approach is to show that a lower bound and an upper bound both converge to $x^*$ from an arbitrary starting point. See my discussion below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it converges, one can solve immediately for $a_\infty = \frac{\sqrt k}{\sqrt{k-1}}$.

So define $b_n = a_n \frac{\sqrt{k-1}}{\sqrt k}$. This gives the recursion

$b_{n+1} =  \frac{1}{k} \left(b_{n} + \frac{{k-1}}{b_{n}}\right)$

which, if convergent, gives $b_\infty = 1$.

We will show that a lower bound and an upper bound both converge to $b_\infty = 1$ from an arbitrary starting point. Hence $b_\infty = 1$ is a unique fixed point and convergence is global.

Let's begin with a lower bound.

Using $1/x = 1/(1 + x-1) \ge 1 - (x-1) = 2 -x$ we have

$b_{n+1} =  \frac{1}{k} \left(b_{n} + \frac{{k-1}}{b_{n}}\right) \ge  \frac{1}{k} \left(b_{n} + {{(k-1)}}{(2-b_{n})}\right) = \frac{1}{k} \left(b_{n} (2-k) + {(2k-2)}\right)$

and the RHS establishes a lower bound $b^-_n \le b_n$ given by the recursion $b^-_{n+1} = \frac{1}{k} \left(b^-_{n} (2-k) + {(2k-2)}\right) $.  We can inspect this recursion to see if and where the lower bound converges to.

According to [Banach's contraction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) for iterating fixed points in  the form $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ convergence is guaranteed if the absolute value of the derivative is less than 1, i.e.  $|f'(x)| < 1$, for some interval of $x$ containing the fixed point. Here, for $b^-_n$ in particular, $f(x_n)$ is a line equation and convergence is *global* if the absolute slope is less than 1.

Since the absolute slope $|2-k|/k$ is always $< 1$ for $k > 1$, iterating the lower bound $b^-_n$ converges, and solving  $b^- = \frac{1}{k} \left(b^- (2-k) + {(2k-2)}\right)$ results in the lower bound limit $b^-_\infty= 1$.  So the lower bound converges to the actual value that the original series should attain (if convergent), which proves convergence from below.

Now for the upper bound.

Suppose $b_1 <1$. Then  $b_2 >1$. So let us suppose w.l.o.g. that we start with some $b_1 >1$.

Then we have that

$b_{n+1} =  \frac{1}{k} \left(b_{n} + \frac{{k-1}}{b_{n}}\right) < \frac{1}{k} \left(b_{n} +{{k-1}}\right)$

provided that $b_{n} > 1$. This is certainly true for $n=1$, and we would like to keep it that way.

So we have an upper bound $b^+_n$ given by the recursion

$b^+_{n+1} = \frac{1}{k} \left(b^+_{n} + {{k-1}}\right)$.

Clearly, if $b^+_{n} > 1$, so is $b^+_{n+1} > 1$, so our condition $b^+_{n} > 1$ holds for all $n$, starting with $b^+_{1} > 1$, and we can work with that upper bound.

Now apply again the contraction theorem. Convergence is globally established since the slope is $\frac{1}{k} <1$, and the fixed point can immediately by computed as $b^+_\infty= 1$.

Hence upper and lower bound converge globally to the same value $b_\infty= 1$, which establishes that the original series also converges, from any starting point, to $b_\infty= 1$. $\quad \Box$

Comment: Can you explain "the RHS establishes a lower bound"? Also, what is the definition of the symbol $b^-_n$? Note: I follow the logic up to that sentence (so I have no issue with the inequality established on the previous line). And I have no problem with "the absolute slope $|2-k|/k$ is always $<1$".

Comment: @quasi I explained it in the main text.

Comment: Shouldn't the relevant function $f$ be
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{k}\left(x + \frac{{k-1}}{x}\right)$$
??
$$$$
It has the unique fixed point $x=1$.

Comment: @quasi IF it converges to the fixed point, the fixed point will be 1. But you must prove  that iterations converge. I couldn't do that. What I proved is that a lower bound converges to the same fixed point. What remains to be done is to prove that an upper bound converges as well to the same fixed point.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas.

Comment: Why $b_1<1$ implies $b_2>1$. I can check, when $k>2$, it is right! How about $1<k<2$? Thank you very much! @Andreas

Comment: @Riemann You are right, $1<k<2$ needs extra treatment.

Comment: @Andreas I see, thank you!  I think the case of $1<k<2$ seems easy to deal with!

Comment: @Andreas Excuse me, I have some doubts for the upper bound. $b_1<1$ implies  $b_2>1$, so we can suppose $b_1>1$. But when $b_1>1$, how to guarantee $b_2>1$ and so on? Because $b_n>1$ is needed to make $b_{n+1}<\frac{1}{k} \left(b_{n} +{{k-1}}\right)<b_{n+1}^+$.